# lim of integration of a non-negative function: $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left[\int_a^b (f(x))^n \, dx\right]^\frac{1}{n} = M$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

i'd like very much your help with this one :

given a positive function meaning
$$ f(x) \geq 0 $$
and $f$  is continuous.

Let $$ M = \sup(f(x)) $$ where $x$ belongs to $[a,b]$.

How can i prove that 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left[\int_a^b (f(x))^n \, dx\right]^\frac{1}{n}  = M$$

Comment: If you are luckier than me, you will find this answered here. Or you can observe that $\leq $ is trivial. For the other direction, show that the lhs is greater that $M(1-\epsilon)$ for every $\epsilon>0$, by use of continuity at a point achieving the sup=max.

Comment: To be more precise, you can show that $\limsup\leq M$ and $\liminf \geq M(1-\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

1) Recall that for any positive number $\alpha$, one has 
$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \alpha^{1/n}=1.$$
2) One has the estimate:
$$\biggl(\int_a^b (f(x))^n \,dx\biggr)^{1/n}\le
\biggl(\int_a^b M^n \,dx\biggr)^{1/n}
= (b-a)^{1/n}\cdot M .$$

3)
Let $\epsilon>0$. By continuity of $f$, choose a non-degenerate interval $[c,d]$ such that $f(x)\ge M-\epsilon$ for all $x\in [c,d]$.  Note
$$
\biggl(\int_a^b (f(x))^n\, dx\biggr)^{1/n}\ge \biggl(\int_c^d (M-\epsilon)^n\,dx\biggr)^{1/n} =(M-\epsilon) (d-c)^{1/n}.
$$

Be careful not to imply that the limit exists before proving that it indeed does exist. (From 2), you can show the $\limsup$ is at most $M$; and from $3$, you can show that the $\liminf$ is at least $M$.)

Comment: the first part i understood and know what and why to do.
but i dont understand how can i calim that that expression is greater from $$M -\epsilon$$) ? 
can you please give me more details?

Comment: @eyal $(f(x))^n$ is nonnegative, so integrating over a smaller domain gives a smaller quantity. Thus $\int_a^b (f(x))^n\,dx\ge\int_c^d (f(x))^n\,dx$. Since $f(x)\ge M-\epsilon$ for $x\in [c,d]$, you have $\int_c^d (f(x))^n\,dx \ge \int_c^d (M-\epsilon)^n\,dx$.

Comment: great, thats what i suspected.
thank you very much!